# Cannot deserialize java.time.Instant

Tags: jackson, java.time.instant

I have a RestEasyClient that has to deserialize an object that has a `java.time.Instant` inside. I tried to register the new JavaTimeModule from jsr310 but still got errors:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .register(mapper)
            .build();
    ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath(SERVICE_URL + "/api"));
```

**Error:**

> Can not construct instance of java.time.Instant: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)

After modifying Rest Server to properly serialize the Instant class (ex: "fromTime": 1525681860)

**New Error:**

> Can not construct instance of java.time.Instant: no double/Double-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1.52568186E9)

I managed to simulate this:

```
    ObjectMapper deserializer = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    Instant probe = deserializer.readValue("1525681860", Instant.class);
    System.out.println(probe);
```

If I remove the "registerModule" line, I get the same error.

Therefore, the conclusion is that RestEasyClient not registering the module. I am definitely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a [`ContextResolver`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html) for [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```java
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        this.mapper = createObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }

    private ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

And then register the resolver in your client instance:

```java
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
    .register(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class).build();
```

---

Alternatively you could register an instance of [`JacksonJsonProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.html). This class is the basic implementation of JAX-RS abstractions ([`MessageBodyReader`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) and [`MessageBodyWriter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html)) needed for binding JSON content to and from Java objects.

You can use the [constructor](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.html#JacksonJsonProvider(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper)) that accepts an [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) instance.

Comment: Thank's so much. I was pulling my hair yesterday night making on rest api to serialise correctly and another module to consume correctly. I was missing the registering of the resolver in a proper way. Had the Context Resolver in the producer and worked well, but my deserialisation was not done because Jackson didn't know how to construct the object